# Using Lync client in Office Communications Server 2007 R2 environment, is it possible?

Tags: office-communicator-2007, lync

Is there really a way to use Lync client in a OCS 2007 R2 environment?
I've found a registry hack but it does not seem to work.

```
Key: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Communicator
Name:  DisableServerCheck
Type: DWORD
Value: 1 (00000001)
```

Is there any other way or any special step to add this hack?

Thanks.
Regards.

Answer (score 3):

Late answer but hopefully it will help someone who finds this from a search.  For Lync 2013, I had to use this:

```
Key: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Lync
Name:  DisableServerCheck
Type: DWORD
Value: 1 (00000001)
```

NOTE: You may need to create some of the keys.

Answer (score 1):

What you have done should work, as witnessed by numerous people in the thread :
[Using Lync 2010 client in Office Communications Server 2007 R2 environment](http://ms-uc.herber.co/?p=105).

However, there seem to be several possible gotchas, having to do with older installations of OCS on the same computer.

A guy named haytham in the above thread found that :

> I solved the problem and it work fine now, what i did is installed the
>   old ocs client, do the registery changes then installed the lync
>   client then it works :)
>
> in the beginning i was uninstalling the old client before install the
>   new and was not working i think it need to not unistall the old ocs
>   2007 client just upgrade it to new ver.

I suggest to read carefully the thread and all comments to try and see what the problem is.

Comment: Hi harrymc, Thanks for answering. I've tried all the things mentioned in that website (that was my source by the way) and nothing seems to work. Also I couldn't find any official document on that hack, but I'm starting to believe that there's an option for the server administrator to override that setting.

Comment: Yes, this has worked correctly for too many people, so it must be something that is particular to your setup.